# I/O-Efficient graph coloring

Tags: algorithms, graphs, colorings

I have an undirected Graph $G$, which is stored in the form of an adjacency list in external memory.

I'm looking for an I/O efficient algorithm which computes a valid coloring for $G$ with at most $k+1$ colors where I provide the $k$.

I tried searching for I/O efficient graph coloring algorithms but couldn't find anything which suits my needs. I would appreciate any pointers to websites/books/papers which could help me with this problem.

I have an internal memory of size $M$ and a practically unlimited amount of external memory. Data is transfered from external to internal memory in blocks of size $B$. By I/O-efficient algorithms I mean algorithms which are designed to minimize the number of transfers between internal and external memory.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by an "I/O efficient algorithm". How would you define I/O efficiency? Are you trying to minimize number of reads from storage, where storage is the external adjacency list? Can you load the adjacency list into memory first or can you only access it from storage?

Comment: @ryan good point, I updated the question. I can access data that has been loaded to internal memory "for free", the main goal is to avoid loading data from external memory as much as possible.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If the graph is small enough to store in memory, just load it into memory and do whatever you want. (You need to read the whole adjacency list eventually, anyway, so you can't hope to do better than this.) If the graph is too large to store in memory, surely it'll take infeasibly long to find a colouring anyway. (Also, why do you specify $k$ to get the algorithm to produce a $k+1$ colouring?)

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's the point, the graph doesn't fit into memory (only parts of it can be in internal memory at one point in time), the algorithm is supposed to compute a valid coloring with as little external memory accesses as possible. The number of such accesses can vary dramatically between algorithms, the coloring doesn't have to be infeasible, I'm not looking for the minimal number of colors.